# Functor sometimes acting covariantly, sometimes contravariantly

Tags: category-theory

I'm a category theory beginner.

Let $\mathbb{P}(A)$ and $\mathbb{P}(B)$ be powerset Boolean algebras. We have that $\mathbb{P}(A+B) \cong \mathbb{P}(A) \times \mathbb{P}(B)$: that is, the functor $\mathbb{P}$ from sets to Boolean algebras is acting "contravariantly" here, taking a coproduct to a corresponding product. (It takes arrows $f: A \to B$ to arrows $\mathbb{P}(f): \mathbb{P}(A) \to \mathbb{P}(B)$, by $\mathbb{P}(f): U \mapsto \{ f(u) : u \in U \}$.)

However, $\mathbb{P}$ is not a contravariant functor. Indeed, $\mathbb{P}(i)$ is the inclusion arrow, so it can't possibly run $\mathbb{P}(B) \to \mathbb{P}(A)$.

What about equalisers? Let $A$ be a two-point set $\{0, 1\}$, and let $B$ be $\{0, 1, 2\}$. Write $i: A \to B$ for the inclusion, and $j: A \to B$ by $j: n \mapsto 2n$. Then the equaliser is the inclusion $e: \{0\} \to A$; the equaliser of $\mathbb{P}(i)$ and $\mathbb{P}(j)$ is $\mathbb{P}(e): \mathbb{P}(\{0\}) \to \mathbb{P}(A)$. So $\mathbb{P}$ is acting covariantly on the equaliser.

Is this an example of a more general phenomenon - that a functor takes one kind of limit to its corresponding colimit, but another kind of limit to the same kind of limit? Or is it just a quirk of this particular functor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two powerset functors, one covariant and one contravariant, given by taking the image resp. the inverse image of a subset. The covariant powerset functor does not take values in Boolean algebras; only the contravariant one does. You should be careful about which one you're using, and also about which category you think it takes values in.

The contravariant powerset functor is a contravariant functor from sets to Boolean algebras, and it sends colimits to limits. The covariant powerset functor is only a covariant functor from sets to sets, and I don't know if it has any nice behavior with respect to either limits or colimits.

Comment: The covariant powerset functor is a monad. Specifically, it is the one associated with complete join semilattices. So we can think of it as a left adjoint functor from sets to complete join semilattices, if we like.

Comment: @ZhenLin I'm enough of a beginner not to know what adjoints are, at the moment, though I do see that it's a monad (in the sense of "monoid in the category of endofunctors"). I'll save this comment for when I've learnt what an adjoint is :)

Comment: Adjoints are more fundamental than monads – I urge you to learn about those sooner rather than later.